# Alternative definition of the Cantor Set

Tags: cantor-set

The Cantor Set $C$ can be defined as taking the interval $C_0=[0,1]$

then $C_1=[0, \frac{1}{3}] \cup [\frac{2}{3},1]$

then $C_2=[0, \frac{1}{9}] \cup [\frac{2}{9},\frac{1}{3}] \cup [\frac{4}{9},\frac{5}{9}] \cup [\frac{2}{3},\frac{7}{9}] \cup [\frac{8}{9},1]$

and so on... Basically this definition involves splitting up the interval and then taking every other segment then $C$ is the intersection of all these so it still creates the same Cantor set in the end.

My question is what is the formula for $C_n$?

Comment: See:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2461773/what-is-the-cantor-set-how-do-i-write-it-mathematically

Comment: The formula given in your linked post wouldn't give $C_2$ in my post

Comment: Your $C_2$ is incorrect.

Comment: I know it is not the usual way that the Cantor set is constructed, but surely after you do this and then take the intersection of all them you will get the same Cantor set no?

Comment: The intersection of $C_1$ and $C_2$ gives the intervals of the second step of the „usual“ method, so yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$C_n$ is the union over $[k/3^n,(k+1)/3^n]$ where $k = 0,2,...$ up to the largest even number less than $3^n$.

Comment: Your formula is incorrect with $n=2$.

Comment: what do you think is incorrect?

Comment: For $n=2$, according to your formula: $C_2= \bigcup_{k=0}^{\lfloor 3^2/2\rfloor}\left[\frac{2k}{3^2},\frac{2k+1}{3^2}\right]= \bigcup_{k=0}^{4}\left[\frac{2k}{9},\frac{2k+1}{9}\right]=[0,1/9] \cup [2/9,3/9] \cup [4/9,5/9] \cup [6/9,7/9]$ $\cup [8/9,1]$. We know that $[4/9,5/9]$ is not an interval of $C_2$.

Comment: be careful! to get the cantor set you still need to take the intersections of all $C_n$, which is also stated in the question.

Comment: But you said "$C_n$  is the union over..."

Comment: yes, of course, since after that the intersection gives $C$.

Comment: It will be much more clearer if you edit your answer to reflect that.

Comment: I don't see any problem, since the original question asks for the definition of $C_n$ and not the cantor set $C$.

Answer (score 2):

It's
$$\bigcap_{n=0}^\infty\left(\bigcup_{i=0}^{\lfloor 3^n/2\rfloor}\left[\frac{2i}{3^n},\frac{2i+1}{3^n}\right]\right)$$

Comment: Hm, I think you are missing some intervals? Whats with $[8/9,1]$ or $[26/27,1]$?

Comment: @T'x You're right. Sometimes I write faster than I think. And sometimes I submit faster than I read what I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

"The formula" is the one we want to give. To understand the idea of the following construction, I refer to my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289803/1-4-is-in-the-cantor-set/4889152#4889152).

Let $$C_0=D_0:=[0,1]$$  $$C_1=D_1=[0,\frac13]\cup[\frac23,1]$$

The idea I'm going to try to formalize is that if we enlarge three times from step to step, give or take, the non-integer part of $x$ must belong to $C_1$.

Let then$$D_2:=\{x\in [0,1]|9x-\left\lfloor  9x\right\rfloor\in
C_1\}$$ $$C_2:=C_1\cap D_2$$
[image]
and, by induction, $$\forall n\ge3, D_n:=\{x\in [0,1]|3^nx-\left\lfloor  3^nx\right\rfloor\in
C_1\}$$ $$\boxed{C_n:=C_{n-1}\cap D_n}$$